# correlated query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I have some records as follows

```
Model            Make            Color
==================================================
Maruti 800       2008            Black
Maruti 800       2009            White
Maruti Esteem    2000            Yelow
Maruti Esteem    2010            Red
```

Now I want the Model, Make and Color which has maximum make in the list.
I have tried writing query like this

```
SELECT 
     Model,
     MAX(Model),
     Color
from 
     tableName
GROUP BY 
     Model,
     Color
```

But the result are not coming which I would like
It should be like

```
Model            Make            Color
===================================================
Maruti 800       2009            White    
Maruti Esteem    2010            Red
```

But the result is the whole table.

I need only those record which has max Make Model Wise.
I have also tried inner Query (co-related query) But in that also it is asking for group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below supports on all RDBMS including `MySQL`, `Oracle`, `SQL Server`,...

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Model, MAX(Make) maxMake
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY Model
        ) b ON a.Model = b.model AND
                a.make = b.MaxMake
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78919/1)

if your RDBMS supports windows function,

```
SELECT  Model, Make, Color
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  Model, Make, Color,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Model ORDER BY Make DESC) rn
            FROM tableName
        ) b 
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78919/2)

or

```
WITH lists
AS
(
    SELECT  Model, Make, Color,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Model ORDER BY Make DESC) rn
    FROM tableName
) 
SELECT  Model, Make, Color
FROM    lists
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78919/3)

Comment: you're welcome. by the way, what database server you are using?

Comment: I would also like if you can explain the differences in all the three examples. And If I have million of records then which will be best to use.